# Click Event Handler Issue

Tags: c#

I am making a quick application which displays a random number onto a second windows Form. I am making it as a random number generator as when the random number is displayed from the click button event handler. I am having trouble figuring out how to display my random generated number onto my new windows Form. I have created two Forms. Here is my code below:

```
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int randomnumber;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            randomnumber = rnd.Next(100);
            Form2 r2 = new Form2();
            r2.ShowDialog();

            MessageBox.Show( randomnumber.ToString()); 
// as you see, I displayed it to a MessageBox because
// I was having difficulty showing this value onto the second windows forum named Form 2 
        }
    }
}

// note, this is the code for the first form.
```

and below is my code for the second form:

```
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having? Where are you trying to display it?

Comment: put a `label` on your `Form2` then after instantiating the form, access the label in that form and assign the **random** value to and then display the form (ex: `r2.label5.Text=randomnumber;`).

Comment: Okay, So the label I created was named label5 in my form 2. How would I assign the random value and display it to the second form?

Answer (score 2):

**Option 01**

You can create a method in Form2 that would assign the value to desired Label control.

```
public void AssignRandomNumber(int randomNumber)
{
    label5.Text = randomNumber.ToString();
}
```

And then after generating the Random Number, you can use the method to assign the value.

```
 randomnumber = rnd.Next(100);
 Form2 r2 = new Form2();
 r2.AssignRandomNumber(randomnumber);
 r2.ShowDialog();
```

**Option 2:**

You could do the same with the Constructor of Form2

```
public Form2(int randomNumber)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    label1.Text = randomNumber.ToString();
}
```

In this case, your code in Form1 would look like

```
randomnumber = rnd.Next(100);
Form2 r2 = new Form2(randomnumber);
r2.ShowDialog();
```